# Find similar HTML parts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, traversal

I have following (simplified) HTML code and want to split it into similar parts:

```
<input id="checkbox1"><label><br>
<input id="checkbox2"><label><br>
<input id="checkbox3"><label><br>
```

The result for this should be `<input><label><br>`. But the problem is, I need a bulletproof solution, which would for example return `<div><p><input></p><p><label></p></div>` from the following HTML:

```
<div><p><input id="checkbox1"></p><p><label></p></div>
<div><p><input id="checkbox2"></p><p><label></p></div>
<div><p><input id="checkbox3"></p><p><label></p></div>
```

Any idea how to find such a pseudo parent element in JavaScript/jQuery?

---

Like [Rory McCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan) figured out, this is indeed used for a templates system. The user defines one row in this template, like `<input id="checkbox1"><label><br>` which is then displayed x times on the screen. I need this template in my JS code, but there is unfortunately no direct access to the user template, so my idea was to figure out which HTML parts look similar and the splitting them to get the template back.

Comment: This sounds like a part of a bigger problem. Is it some form of templating you're trying to implement?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that this are user generated templates, the only two requirements are the `<input>` and the `<label>` elements, all other elements are optional. I don't want to force the user to define a parent element.

Comment: Should repeating tags with different content be considered a match, or only if the tags *and* content are the same?

Comment: Tags with different content should be matched. Updated the example.

Comment: I think your are getting this code at run-time, Or you have some input you are getting with user from any form. In that case you need to use regex to replace your code with new code you want. IF you can show me code with proper way u are getting i can try to send you regex.

Comment: What happens if the third `div` contains a text node instead of the two paragraphs? That still fulfills the `Tags with different content should be matched` criteria.

Comment: @Asad, except that he said it has to include an input and a label to be considered a match.

Comment: @davidethell Oh right, missed that comment. That should be in the question.

Comment: Is that last `<div>` supposed to be a closing tag?

Comment: Don't be tempted down the regexp route. It is generally accepted that regexps cannot reliably parse/manipulate freely written HTML. You can use what's known as event-based parsing however there's generally no need because every browser already has a thoroughly reliable, error-tolerant HTML parser at its core. Literally millions of man-hours have gone into the development and perfection of these parsers and, in a browser-based application, are available for you to exploit. jQuery makes it very simple to create a DOM fragment, manipulate it, then optionally read back synthetically created HTML.

Answer (score 1):

As a partial solution, you could consider identifying the closest common ancestor for an input label pair, and using this as the repeating element:

```
var collection = $('');
$('input').each(function() {
    collection = collection
        .add($(this)
             .parents(':has(label)')
             .filter(function() {
                 return $(this).siblings().length == $(this).siblings(this.tagName).length;
             }));
});
console.log(collection);
```

This presupposes each label input pair *has* a common parent element, and so doesn't work for your first case.

Comment: Thank you, I'm already using such a solution, which worked perfectly until one user entered the first HTML example. ;)

Comment: My idea was to build a tree and then search top-down for similar subtrees, but I don't know if this is an overkill.